# Is it possible to exclude some commits from semantic release release notes?

Tags: github-actions, commit, release, semantic-release

I have a case where I need to include the commit in the `semantic-release/commit-analyzer` but not in `semantic-release/release-notes-generator`. Is it possible to do this in Github actions semantic release?

Comment: What is the commit? Is this a once off, or will it keep recurring?

Comment: It will come every 2weeks with an automated commit but need in commit analysis.

Answer (score 1):

Semantic-release will only (by default) include commits which trigger a release in the release notes.  So commits which e.g. begin with `ci:` or `refactor:` don't make it through.*  I *think* this is your usecase here---an automated commit which triggers some action but does not in itself constitute a release.

**Update** it seems you really do want to trigger a version bump without documenting what you did.  I think that's a bad idea (expanded below), but it is possible with a hack like this:

### Silent Commits

The whole point of semantic-release is that every version-bump-worthy change is documented.  However if you really want to produce a hidden bump, you can use a hack along the lines of:

1. save latest tag to a var or file
2. run semantic release *without* the `@semantic-release/github` action, but *with* the `@semantic-release/changelog` action, writing the changelog somewhere that the git release will not pick it up, i.e. outside the cloned dir.
3. run a custom script which:

- parses your changelog.md
- gets the most recent release notes (easy: parse by headline)
- checks whether you have released, i.e. if the first headline tag is not the tag you got in step 1.
- strips out the 'bad' line
- outputs to stdout (redirect to a var) or writes somewhere

4. iff there is some output, create the github release yourself, using one of the various actions, and set the *message* to be the output from your script.

### Reasons not to do this

I'm just some random guy on the internet, but I *don't* think this is a good idea.  Reasoning:

The whole point about semantic-release is to make releasing 'boring and unromantic': more specifically that every release-worthy commit triggers a *documented* release.  Now either your automated `fix: stuff` commit *does* actually fix stuff (in which case this is noteworthy and should be included), or it *doesn't*, in which case you have some other problem (maybe you are trying to release for 'romantic and interesting' reasons?  Maybe you need a release every n days even if nothing has actually changed?).  In either case, hiding a legitimate fix is not the way to go about it.

If your problem is a kind of 'microfix' which should generate a release, but happens so frequently as to clog up the release notes, you *might* want a prerelease branch (where lots of microfixs get rolled up into one big fix in the merge commit).

*assuming you're using [conventional commits](https://gist.github.com/Zekfad/f51cb06ac76e2457f11c80ed705c95a3)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have some commit named "fix: Updated some definitions", This commit I want to participate in commit analysis for the version bump, but don't want to include in the release notes.

Comment: I still don't know *why* you want to do this, but I've updated the answer to make it clearer how you can hack this in github actions.  But per my comments I think this might be an x/y problem (I could definitely be wrong, though).

Comment: Sometimes there is just a typo in the README.md or similar auxillary files which is not packaged in a release artifact.